# Why isn't my Python exception being re-raised?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I have a function within a module, that does something like this:

```
def some_func():

    try:
        # do some error-prone thing
        raise ValueError
        return 'calculated foo'
    except AttributeError as err:
        # handle it
        pass
    except:
        print('Some other error happened, let\'s reraise it....')
        raise
    else:
        pass
    finally:
        return 'default foo'
```

Then within my main program,

```
try:
    val = some_func()
    print('val=', val)
except:
    print('In main except')
    raise
else:
    print('In main else')
    pass
finally:
    print('And we\'re done')
```

My output is:

> Some other error happened, let's reraise it....
>
> val= default foo
>
> In main else
>
> And we're done

**No exception is raised.**

At the risk of missing something obvious, why isn't the `ValueError` being reraised within my main?  It almost seems like the `return` within my `finally` in `some_func()` is causing the exception not to be reraised, but this seems odd to me and I can't find any documentation of it.  Here's what I think should be happpening, would like to understand where I'm off.

1. I call `some_func()` within my main program
2. `some_func()` raises ValueError
3. The ValueError is caught within the `some_func()` `except`, prints "Some other error happened" and reraises it.
4. Back in main, I *thought* the reraised ValueError should get caught by the `except`, should print 'In main except', reraise, and then the exception itself should be uncaught causing the program to halt.  But I get no exception raised and wind up in the `else` clause instead.

Comment: if you're expecting the exception stack to be unwound after executing the finally block ... why is it returning a value?

Comment: This is an example, but my understanding is it should make no difference.  From the documentation, "If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the exception may be handled by an except clause. If the exception is not handled by an except clause, the exception is re-raised after the finally clause has been executed."  So isn't the fact that my `finally` returns a value irrelevant to reraising the exeption?

Comment: No. For what you are trying to do, the return should be in the "else" block, not the "finally" block. Python would have to re-raise the exception *before* returning because after returning the exception would no longer exist to be re-raised.There are really only two reasonable ways python could treat this code: (1) execute the return, aborting any ongoing stack-unwind for an exception, which is what it does, or (2) as a syntax error

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, pylint will give you a warning on that line if you give it this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behavior and [described in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> If `finally` is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. (...) If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved. (...) If the `finally` clause executes a `return`, `break` or `continue` statement, the saved exception is discarded

Comment: That clarifies it.  I was looking at the language here, seems it should be noted here as well: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions.